# Где лучше хранить token телеграм бота?

Tags: java, telegram-bot, token

Делаю своего первого телеграмм-бота. На Java в IntelliJ IDEA.

В мануале по созданию бота советуют: "... хранить ваш токен в специальном файле настроек или в переменных среды..."

Сейчас токен у меня прямо в методе:

```
@Override
    public String getBotToken() {
        return "0123456789:A3gj34gjsdg023sd092gj344g4g";
    }
```

Подскажите, где лучше хранить - В файле настроек? или в Переменных среды?
Чем эти способы отличаются и как реализовываются?

Comment: Зависит от того, насколько вы обеспокоены безопастностью. Например, вы сейчас храните в коде, а значит, если вылодите код куда либо (тот же github), то все сразу увидят ваш токен и сделают с ним всё, что захотят.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Лучше хранить токен в отдельном `config.java` файле, но это зависит от того, где и как вы будете публиковать бота, и насколько вам важна секурность. Если вы собираетесь сделать его опенсорс, то лучше всего хранить в конфиге, но при этом не заливая в репозиторий сам конфиг (а залить лишь код, с указанием его импорта). А насчёт самого хостинга, куда вы будете заливать код, то тут уже как вам удобнее - главное, чтобы к хостингу никто не имел доступа кроме вас. Надеюсь, ответил на ваш вопрос :)